# Is Topmage extension database safe?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

Has anyone downloaded extensions from ext.topmage.com before? Is this site safe?

I am asking because I need to download the free Disable Compare Products extension.

Answer (score 0):

site is probably safe,
but some links can be outdated. if you check on magento connect , some extensions have different version number.

you need to download from magento connect.